# Example of a group with some property

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can anyone give  an example of a group $G$ and normal subgroups $N_1,\ldots,N_n$ such that $G = N_1N_2\ldots N_n$ and $N_i \cap N_j$ = (e) for $i \neq j$ and yet $G$ is not  the internal direct product of $N_1,\ldots,N_n$ ?

> > I donot know if there is a well-known example about this. Could anyone give such an example? Or any references ?

Thank you.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634261/direct-product-of-more-than-2-groups/

Comment: Thanks your reply, whatever I am not familiar with $C_n$ groups , if any other example in your mind, tell me.

Comment: $C_n$ is the cyclic group of order $n$.

Comment: That is standard notation by the way.

Answer (score 1):

The most well-behaved groups of all are vector spaces under addition. Might as well pick something that's just one level above trivial, so let's take $\Bbb R^2$ (reals because of their familiarity). Pick any three distinct lines through the origin (these will be trivially intersecting subspaces).

In this example, it should be geometrically "obvious" that any number of any distinct lines will do the trick just as well, so the hypothesis fails as badly as it can. In general, if a group is a product of normal subgroups that are trivially intersecting, it's *still* pretty miraculous for it to be direct. Quantitatively one could pick various cases where one could measure how rare, and you'd likely get probability zero.